# find arabic word in a string with Nunation

Tags: android, arabic-support

i want find a Arabic word with Nunation in a TextView  and highlight this,
for example if my  word is "اشهد" whitout Nunation  i want to find word position in "وَ اَشْهَدُ اَنْ لا اِلهَ اِلاَّ اللَّهُ" with Nunation .

Comment: the best thing I can suggest to use is regex....I'll try to find the correct regex for your need

Answer (score 3):

Hi Please see below class i created. It is so basic and did not bother about memory consumption. You guys can optimise yourself.

http://freshinfresh.com/sample/ABHArabicDiacritics.java

If you want to check without nunation(harakath) contains in an arabic String,

```
    ABHArabicDiacritics objSearchd = new ABHArabicDiacritics();
objSearchdobjSearch.getDiacriticinsensitive("وَ اَشْهَدُ اَنْ لا اِلهَ اِلاَّ اللَّهُ").contains("اشهد");
```

If you want to return Highlighed or redColored searched portion in String.
Use below code

```
ABHArabicDiacritics objSearch = new ABHArabicDiacritics( وَ اَشْهَدُ اَنْ لا اِلهَ اِلاَّ اللَّهُ, اشهد);
SpannableString spoutput=objSearch.getSearchHighlightedSpan();
            textView.setText(spoutput);
```

To see start and end position of search text,
Use below methods,

```
 /** to serch Contains */
            objSearch.isContain();//
            objSearch.getSearchHighlightedSpan();
            objSearch.getSearchTextStartPosition();
            objSearch.getSearchTextEndPosition();
```

Please copy shared java class and enjoy.

I will spend more time for more feature if you guys request.

Thanks

Comment: link returns 404 error!
can you please copy the class here or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

search ولد  in INPUT :
 public void RegexMatches() {

```
    String INPUT  ="ى لَیْلَهِ تَمامِهِ وَکَمالِهِ فَما کانَتْ اِلاّ ساعَهً وَاِذا بِوَلَدِىَ الْحَسَنِ قَدْ" ;


    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("و[\\u064B-\\u064F\\u0650-\\u0656]*ل[\\u064B-\\u064F\\u0650-\\u0656]*د");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);   // get a matcher object
    int count = 0;

    while(m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Match number "+count);
        System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
        System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me by replacing unicode diacritics(harakat):

```
  private String normalize(){

    //Remove honorific sign
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0610", "");//ARABIC SIGN SALLALLAHOU ALAYHE WA SALLAM
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0611", "");//ARABIC SIGN ALAYHE ASSALLAM
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0612", "");//ARABIC SIGN RAHMATULLAH ALAYHE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0613", "");//ARABIC SIGN RADI ALLAHOU ANHU
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0614", "");//ARABIC SIGN TAKHALLUS

    //Remove koranic anotation
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0615", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH TAH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0616", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE ALEF WITH LAM WITH YEH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0617", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH ZAIN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0618", "");//ARABIC SMALL FATHA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0619", "");//ARABIC SMALL DAMMA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u061A", "");//ARABIC SMALL KASRA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06D6", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE SAD WITH LAM WITH ALEF MAKSURA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06D7", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE QAF WITH LAM WITH ALEF MAKSURA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06D8", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH MEEM INITIAL FORM
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06D9", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH LAM ALEF
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DA", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH JEEM
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DB", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH THREE DOTS
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DC", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH SEEN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DD", "");//ARABIC END OF AYAH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DE", "");//ARABIC START OF RUB EL HIZB
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06DF", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH ROUNDED ZERO
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E0", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH UPRIGHT RECTANGULAR ZERO
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E1", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH DOTLESS HEAD OF KHAH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E2", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH MEEM ISOLATED FORM
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E3", "");//ARABIC SMALL LOW SEEN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E4", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH MADDA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E5", "");//ARABIC SMALL WAW
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E6", "");//ARABIC SMALL YEH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E7", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH YEH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E8", "");//ARABIC SMALL HIGH NOON
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06E9", "");//ARABIC PLACE OF SAJDAH
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06EA", "");//ARABIC EMPTY CENTRE LOW STOP
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06EB", "");//ARABIC EMPTY CENTRE HIGH STOP
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06EC", "");//ARABIC ROUNDED HIGH STOP WITH FILLED CENTRE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u06ED", "");//ARABIC SMALL LOW MEEM

    //Remove tatweel
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0640", "");

    //Remove tashkeel
    input=input.replaceAll("\u064B", "");//ARABIC FATHATAN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u064C", "");//ARABIC DAMMATAN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u064D", "");//ARABIC KASRATAN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u064E", "");//ARABIC FATHA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u064F", "");//ARABIC DAMMA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0650", "");//ARABIC KASRA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0651", "");//ARABIC SHADDA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0652", "");//ARABIC SUKUN
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0653", "");//ARABIC MADDAH ABOVE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0654", "");//ARABIC HAMZA ABOVE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0655", "");//ARABIC HAMZA BELOW
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0656", "");//ARABIC SUBSCRIPT ALEF
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0657", "");//ARABIC INVERTED DAMMA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0658", "");//ARABIC MARK NOON GHUNNA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0659", "");//ARABIC ZWARAKAY
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065A", "");//ARABIC VOWEL SIGN SMALL V ABOVE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065B", "");//ARABIC VOWEL SIGN INVERTED SMALL V ABOVE
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065C", "");//ARABIC VOWEL SIGN DOT BELOW
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065D", "");//ARABIC REVERSED DAMMA
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065E", "");//ARABIC FATHA WITH TWO DOTS
    input=input.replaceAll("\u065F", "");//ARABIC WAVY HAMZA BELOW
    input=input.replaceAll("\u0670", "");//ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF
    input=input.replace("\u0671", "\u0627")
    return input;
}
```